# Side scrolling detection is not consistently reliable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working on a React application with Next.js. On one of my pages, I've implemented side scrolling for a table. Additionally, I've developed a function to determine if a user is doing side scrolling or not.

```
const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  const tableRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (tableRef.current) {
      const element = tableRef.current as HTMLDivElement;
      if (element.scrollLeft > 0) {
        setIsScrolling(true);
      } else {
        setIsScrolling(false);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tableRef.current && horizontalScrollEnabled) {
      const element = tableRef.current as HTMLDivElement;
      element.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

      // Return cleanup function
      return () => {
        element.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      };
    }
  }, [tableRef.current, horizontalScrollEnabled]);
```

then I have this to change the background of the first column when ever the side scroll is set to true:

```
const firstColumnStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    background: isScrolling ? "red" : "",
  };
```

However, there's an issue with its consistency. Sometimes the side scrolling functionality works as expected, while at other times, it does not. I've implemented filtering and sorting features, and I've seen that the side scroll effect seems to function properly when I interact with these filters or sort the columns. However, when I initially load the page and attempt side scrolling, it only detects the action half of the time. Even after refreshing the page, it won't recognize side scrolling until I trigger any filtering or sorting actions from the table.

This is how I have configured my table:

```
 <div className={horizontalScrollEnabled ? styles.scroll : ""} ref={tableRef}>
        <BootstrapTable>
        .
        .
        .
        </ BootstrapTable>
 </div>
```